# JSDate - Parse a ddMMyyyy format date correctly

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

I've having trouble with parsing user input with Javascript, where I can't get the parser  to accept dates in ddMMyyyy correctly. It parses correctly when there are separator characters.

The example below is using [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) (NZ localised), and I've had an initial attempt with the newer [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/) (which isn't proving ideal for input validation). I'm open to other frameworks, if they're going to handle input cases adequately.

My test cases:

```
// Parses correct value
var dateWithHyphens = Date.parse('01-06-2012');

// Parses incorrectly, using MMddyyy, instead of ddMMyyyy
var dateWithoutHyphens = Date.parse('01062012');

// Parses incorrectly, using MMddyyy, instead of ddMMyyyy
var dateWithFormat = Date.parse('01062012', { format: 'ddMMyyyy'});
```

I've created a JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ajwxs/1

The test cases should return 1 June, but the incorrect ones return Jan 06. (That this is input parsing - output formatting is too late).

Any suggestions on if JSDate can be better prodded to use the correct format for parsing those dates?

### Update

In this application, I'm validating a number of possible user inputs, including:

```
01062012
01/06/2012
010612
```

This would make an implementation of a parseExact-style implementation a bit verbose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Date.parseExact](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) method. For some reason it works while the normal parse does not. Also you don't need to pass the format option wrapped in an object.

According to the spec Date.parse is not supposed to take a format option so that is probably why.

```
// Parses correctly
var dateWithFormat = Date.parseExact('01062012', 'ddMMyyyy');
```

I have also updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBZJx/) to be sure.

### Update

I think the issue is that the parser [hard-codes](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/parser.js#921) a bunch of simple formats and those override the localization setting for the date, month and year order in some cases. If you put the following before where you use Date it will fix your issue.

```
Date.Grammar._formats = Date.Grammar.formats([
    "\"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ\"",
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssz",
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ",
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmz",
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm",
    "ddd, MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
    "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz",
    "ddMMyyyy",
    "MMddyyyy",
    "ddMyyyy",
    "Mddyyyy",
    "dMyyyy",
    "Mdyyyy",
    "yyyy",
    "dMyy",
    "Mdyy",
    "d"
]);
```

This is not pretty but it is definitely shorter than listing all of the possible options, if only by a little bit. If you can find a less quirky Date library that might be a better option.

Comment: Updated the question to include a wider range of expected user input. I will look into implementing your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about DateJS, but if you've found that it is assuming `MMddyyyy` where you want `ddMMyyyy` then you could do a quick replace on your string to switch it to `MMddyyyy` before parsing:

```
Date.parse( '01062012'.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)$/,"$2$1$3") );
```

Or do a similar replace to insert hyphens and make it `dd-MM-yyyy`:

```
Date.parse( '01062012'.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)$/,"$1-$2-$3") );
```

Either way a string that already had hyphens in it would be left unchanged and thus be parsed as per your first (successful) test case.

Comment: The rest of the module is set to use the dmy format. The regex is a slippery slope, having to test for all cases the date module already knows about - mixtures of 1-2 digit day + months, and 2 or 4 digit years...

Comment: Yes, it's not ideal, but then a mixture of 1 digit day or month wouldn't really work at all without separators, because, e.g., what date is 111972 - 1/1/1972 or 11/19/72? If you assume that a string that has no separators it must be in `ddMMyyyy` format then the regex in my answer should do the trick since it doesn't change strings with separators and you've already said that strings with separators work the way you want. (I hope somebody else posts a better answer, but if not at least this will work...)